# Items in a flex container are overlapping

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following stylesheet:

```
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #888;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

  .gallery-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;

    .image {
      display: block;
      width: auto;
      max-width: 100vw;
      opacity: .5;

      .inner-image {
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I am using it with the following markup:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="..." class="inner-image">
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="..." class="inner-image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is that the elements are overlapping when I load the page:

[image]

After I resize the browser window, or zoom-in & zoom-out they appear stacked, next to each other, which is the desired behavior.

What is wrong here?

P.S. Here is a [pen](https://codepen.io/victorbarbu/pen/rJvEBo)

Comment: it's working fine for me

Comment: even if you go on codepen?

Comment: @TemaniAfif however on codepen the effect is different: the first image is rendered out of the view (in the left side) and after a resize of the window or zoom-in/zoom-out, it goes in the desired position

Comment: @TemaniAfif change the height of the gallery class. you can see overlapping

Comment: Check this out https://codepen.io/bahiirwa/pen/MQGNVe

Comment: yes  i see, add flex:1 to `.gallery .gallery-container .image` and it will fix the issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif not working for me

Comment: @Victor Have you tried adding `overflow: hidden` to `.image` class

Comment: @HarunDilukaHeshan this would make half of the image to render

Comment: Looks like when I give a pixels value to `height` of the `.inner-image` class, the browser renders them correctly but I need a percentage because the height of the gallery is relative to the height of the window

Comment: Can't you give `.inner-image` height in vh?

Comment: @Izabela this seems to work fine. However I am not sure if I will be able to stick with the `50vh` value because at some point in the near future, I might introduce some `@query`-es to this and I would have to repeat code a lot

Comment: I think it also works if you add `height:100%`  to `.gallery .gallery-container .image`

Comment: @Izabela unfortunately no. it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

I added the following properties to `.image`:

```
.image {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  flex: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And it renders correctly. Here is the updated [pen](https://codepen.io/victorbarbu/pen/rJvEBo)

Comment: Thanks, had a similar issue which disappeared with flex-shrink : 0